# Katalon disqus textArea Object cannot be recognized

Tags: spring-boot, disqus, katalon-studio

I hava a test through using Katalon System.

Simulation is to leave a comment in Disqus comment textarea
(test website is  https://corus.kaist.edu/research?s_id=1280&u_d=0#12800 )

However this textArea is not recognized even if i write this code

```
WebUI.setText(findTestObject('View/Page_CORUS/div_ _textarea'), 'Katalon tttteeeessstttt')
```

How to solve this problem and there is iframe problem as well?

Comment: How is `'View/Page_CORUS/div_ _textarea'` defined? Also, can you please share your test case script?

Comment: Keep in mind that textarea is inside iframe. So you can't directly find it without going through the iframe document.

Comment: And 2nd thing is the textarea can't be directly accessible , you will have to use getAttribute method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with XPath. Add XPath manually in the **object repository**.

```
//div/div[@class='textarea']
```

[image]

Hope your problem will be solved.